# Optimizing Dockerfile for smaller image size

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker image which is as small as possible. My project is codded in typescript.

For what I have at the moment, it works just fine, but I'm sure not if my implementation is even good. When I run docker build the image size comes up to 276.23MB.

The problem is that I have to call "tsc" to compile my code into JavaScript which is a dev-dependency.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.11 as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN \ 
    npm install && \
    npm run build

FROM node:16-alpine3.11 
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app .
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

These are the scripts & dependencies in my package.json file:

```
{
...
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "start": "fastify start -l info dist/src/app.js",
    "build": "npx rimraf /dist && tsc",
    "prebuild": "ts-node scripts/clean",
    "docker": "docker build -t barnes-biz/pokemon:1.0.0 .",
    "predocker": "npm run build",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fastify": "^3.0.0",
    "fastify-autoload": "^3.3.1",
    "fastify-cli": "^2.13.0",
    "fastify-helmet": "^5.3.2",
    "fastify-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "fastify-sensible": "^3.1.0",
    "fastify-swagger": "^4.8.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.5",
    "weak-napi": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/rimraf": "^3.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.0",
    "concurrently": "^6.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "fastify-tsconfig": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  }
}
```

I don't seem to understand how to do it. Can you help me? Do you also know some best practices that I should follow writing the Dockerfile or anything else? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- You want to copy the output of the compiler, not the source files
- You still need to install node_modules in the running container, but want to use the production flag to make sure dev dependencies are ignore. The docker file will then look something like this:

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.11 as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./ # A small optimization to allow for caching in between Docker builds
RUN npm ci
COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN npm run build

FROM node:16-alpine3.11 
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --production
COPY --from=build /usr/build/app .  # This line will depend on your tsconfig

RUN ls -la
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

You could alternatively prune your node_modules in the build image and copy that over as well.

Comment: Thanks for the input but this change makes my image larger